# Assign ByteInputStream to InputStream keeping bind to terminal emulator

Tags: java, android, stream, inputstream

I am trying to connect to a terminal emulator using a library in android, this will connect to a serial device and should show me sent/received data. To attach to a terminal session I need to provide an `inputStream` to `setTermIn(InputStream)` and an `outputStream` to `setTermOut(OutputStream)`.

I initialize and attach some streams like so in `onCreate()`, these are just initial streams and are not attached to the data I want to be sending/receiving.

```
private OutputStream bos;
private InputStream bis;

...

byte[] a = new byte[4096];
bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(a);
bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
session.setTermIn(bis);
session.setTermOut(bos);
/* Attach the TermSession to the EmulatorView. */
mEmulatorView.attachSession(session);
```

I now want to assign the streams to data as I send and receive data. In The sendData() method, which I call every time I press enter, I have:

```
public void sendData(byte[] data)
{
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);         
}
```

and in the onReceiveData() method, called every time data is received over serial:

```
public void onDataReceived(int id, byte[] data)
{
        bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);           
}
```

However a `ByteArrayInputStream` can only ever have the data that was given to it, so it constantly needs to be created as data is sent and received. Now the problem is, I want this data to appear on the terminal, but when I assign bis to the data, it is no longer attached like it was when I called `mEmulatorView.attachSession(session);`

Is there a way to update what bis is pointing to without breaking the bind that bis has to the terminal?

EDIT:
Also if I try to call attach again I get errors, although ideally I don't want to be calling it again etc.

```
 SerialTerminalActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                mSession.setTermIn(bis);
                mSession.setTermOut(bos);
                mEmulatorView.attachSession(mSession);
            }
          });
```

Although that may be my coding there.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YNCJ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the ByteArrayInputStream adding the funcionality you need.

As an example:

```
public class MyBAIsWrapper implements InputStream {

   private ByteArrayInputStream wrapped;

   public MyBAIsWrapper(byte[] data) {
       wrapped=new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
   }

   //added method to refresh with new data
   public void renew(byte[] newData) {
       wrapped=new ByteArrayInpurStream(newData);
   }

   //implement the InputStreamMethods calling the corresponding methos on wrapped
   public int read() throws IOException {
      return wrapped.read();
   }

   public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException {
       return wrapped.read(b);
   }

   //and so on

}
```

Then, change your initialization code:

```
byte[] a = new byte[4096];
bis = new MyBAIsWrapper(a);
session.setTermIn(bis);
//here, you could do somethin similar for OoutpuStream if needed, or keep the same initialization...
bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
session.setTermOut(bos);
/* Attach the TermSession to the EmulatorView. */
mEmulatorView.attachSession(session);
```

And change the onDataReceived method to renew the input stream data:

```
public void onDataReceived(int id, byte[] data)
{
    //cast added to keep original code structure 
    //I recomend define the bis attribute as the MyBAIsWrapper type in this case
    ((MyBAIsWrapper)bis).renew(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really liked your answer and used it. However the problem persists so i think I have a problem elsewhere in my code.